# Netbeans Midlet Screen Flow Auto-Organize

Tags: netbeans, midlet

I'm designing this JME application for a Nokia phone and when designing the MIDlet screen flow, my Netbeans is now bunching up all of the forms I designed on top of each other and not in some kind of easy to see diagram. Is there any button or setting I can use to make everything organized again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by clicking a format button in the window next to 'Analyer'. I knew it was something simple.

Comment: Is this how I accept my own answer? I posted this and then stumbled upon the answer a couple hours aferwards. Do I just delete?